# Why the function execute immediately in vue 3 setup block

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I define a function in vue 3 like this:

```
setup(props) {
    
    const { getters } = useStore();

    const add = () => {
      alert("dd");
    };

    return (
      add
    );
  }
```

and invoke it in the template like this:

```
<button type="button" class="translate-pop-button" @click="()=>add">
        <span class="reddwarf-btn-icon"></span>
      </button>
```

now I found the setup function add execute when the component created. why the add function execute immediately? how to avoid it execute automatically? I have tried to write the function invoke like this:

```
@click="()=>add"
```

seems did not work. This is the code how I mount the component:

```
export async function addTransShowElement(translation:string){
  let anchorElementId = "uniq-anchor-point";
  let anchorElement = document.getElementById(anchorElementId);
  if (anchorElement == null || anchorElement === undefined) {
    let reddwarfTranslateDiv = document.createElement("div");
    reddwarfTranslateDiv.id = anchorElementId;
    document.body.appendChild(reddwarfTranslateDiv);
  }
  let appElement = document.getElementById("reddwarf-translate-app");
  if (appElement == null || appElement === undefined) {
    let props = {
      word: translation.toString().trim(),
    };
    const app = createApp(TranslatorPop, props);
    app.use(store);
    let vm = app.mount("#uniq-anchor-point");
    document.body.appendChild(vm.$el);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like in snippet return object not function:

```js
const App = {
  setup() {
    const add = () =>  alert("dd");
    return {   // you was calling it here with ()
      add
    };
  }
}
Vue.createApp(App)
  .mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" class="translate-pop-button" @click="add">
    <span class="reddwarf-btn-icon">click</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually it wasn't called with () but it was treated as rendered function like that and so was called on render